# Call Query from ms access by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i used this funtion to concatenate datarows..

```
Public Function GetList(SQL As String _
                                , Optional ColumnDelimeter As String = ", " _
                                , Optional RowDelimeter As String = vbCrLf) As String
    'PURPOSE: to return a combined string from the passed query
    'ARGS:
    '   1. SQL is a valid Select statement
    '   2. ColumnDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each column
    '   3. RowDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each row
    'RETURN VAL: Concatenated list
    'DESIGN NOTES:
    'EXAMPLE CALL: =GetList("Select Col1,Col2 From Table1 Where Table1.Key = " & OuterTable.Key)

    Const PROCNAME = "GetList"
    Const adClipString = 2
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sResult As String

    On Error GoTo ProcErr

    Set oConn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set oRS = oConn.Execute(SQL)

    sResult = oRS.GetString(adClipString, -1, ColumnDelimeter, RowDelimeter)

    If Right(sResult, Len(RowDelimeter)) = RowDelimeter Then
        sResult = Mid$(sResult, 1, Len(sResult) - Len(RowDelimeter))
    End If

    GetList = sResult
    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close

    CleanUp:
        Set oRS = Nothing
        Set oConn = Nothing

    Exit Function
    ProcErr:
        ' insert error handler
        Resume CleanUp

    End Function
```

the query i used is

```
  SELECT OB.Operation_Type, OB.Machine_Type, OB.Attatchment, GetList("Select Operation_Name From OB As T1 Where T1.Operation_Type = """ & [ob].[Operation_Type] & """ and  T1.Machine_Type = """ & [ob].[Machine_Type] & """ and  T1.Attatchment = """ & [ob].[Attatchment] & """ ",""," + ") AS Expr1 
    FROM ob
    GROUP BY ob.Operation_Type, Machine_Type, Attatchment;
```

Now i need to call this query from vb.net
i tried as follows::

```
myConnection.Open()
        Dim db As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Query", myConnection)

        Try
            cmd.Connection = myConnection
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "Query"
            db.SelectCommand = cmd
            db.Fill(dt)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        myConnection.Close()
```

this is giving error as follows
"Undefined function 'GetList' in expression."

Please Help
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You send the SQL string to Access which then looks for the function *GetList* which it, of course, cannot find.

You will have to rethink your concept.

Comment: Thanks @gustav but i need to run this query on button click event using vb.net

Comment: Can you give me any suggestions..

Comment: Yes, as the other ref. by Gordon also tells, you simply have to use another method.